# Ryu/OpenFlow how to map in_port number to physical port

Tags: python, networking, openflow, ryu

For the uninitiated - I am asking a Python/SDN question. It *is* a programming question.

There isn't much literature on this and I didn't see it in [the specification](https://www.opennetworking.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/openflow-spec-v1.3.3.pdf). I have built a Ryu controller based on [the documentation](https://ryu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_ryu_app.html) and have it all working, but I have a rather simple problem:

How do you map the *in_port* numbers to actual port numbers? In my case, it is saying I have an *in_port* of 5. However, it's actually coming in to physical port 1/1/2 on my Dell 4112F-ON. There doesn't seem to be any correlation between the two.

If I want to control traffic on a per port basis, how do I know from which physical port the traffic came?

Edit: I know how to convert to a MAC address, but I haven't figured out a clean way to programatically determine the port # from the MAC address.

Comment: This appears to be a networking question, not a programming question. You can ask questions about business networks on [sf].

Comment: It is not a networking question. It is a Python question about how to program a Ryu controller to output the physical port of a switch. It’s SDN so at this point it sounds like minor semantics lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that in Ryu, the name of the physical port is inside the dpset data structure which is part of ryu.controller. In dpset there is an attribute called port_state which is a dictionary of type {: }. You can extract the data with the following code:

```
    port_list = []

    for port, port_info in simple_switch.dpset.port_state[dpid].items():
        port_list.append(
            {"hw_addr": port_info.hw_addr, "name": port_info.name.decode("utf-8"), "openflow_port": port})
```

where simpleswitch in my case was an instance of Ryu's REST controller from [here](https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/rest_api.html). However, you don't need to rest to get the data - it is part of the data maintained with the controller in dpset.